ld: framework not found OneSignal React native
I have a React native app v0.71.14 and it uses OneSignalNotifications "react-native-onesignal": "^4.5.2". The app used to build with Xcode v15.3 but ever since I upgraded to Xcode 15.4, the build crashes and it has the following error
ld: framework not found OneSignal
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

The Podfile integration looks like
target 'OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension' do 
  pod 'OneSignal', '>= 3.4.1', '< 4.0'
end

I have tried the following steps mentioned in the troubleshooting guides for OneSignal

removed Podfile.lock and did a pod deintegrate && pod install
Official troubleshooting link OneSignal
Also made changes by referencing the Stackoverflow thread: Framework Search Path update with ${inherited} change
Modified the Header Search Path to have this $(SRCROOT)/../node_modules/react-native-onesignal/ios value and set it recursive as mentioned in the troubleshooting guide.
I have also tried to remove yarn.lock file and did a yarn install.

I am using Node version 18.20.0 and the yarn version is 1.22.22.

I managed to fix this issue by downgrading Xcode to 15.3, deleted node_modules and reinstalled pods.
